# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateStack operation:

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, dockerfile

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateStack operation: User: arn:aws:iam::812520856627:user/dimitris is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateStack on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:812520856627:stack/blog-stage/*
```

I tried to run this on command :

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name blog-stage --template-body file://$PWD/stack.yml --profile demo --region us-west-2
```

```
Resources:
  AppNode:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        ImageId: ami-0c579621aaac8bade
        KeyName: jimapos
        SecurityGroups:
          - !Ref AppNodeSG
  AppNodeSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
        GroupDescription: for the app nodes that allow ssh, http and docker ports
        SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: You don't have valid permission to do that. `user/dimitris is not authorized`

Comment: and how do i change this?

Comment: You have to grant permission through IAM.

Comment: From AWS IAM, give permission to the user for `CreateStack` in Cloud Formation.

Comment: can you be more specific about how can i do that?

Comment: @Lamanus  can you describe me how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to create stack against `User` **dimitris** which is not authorized to perform `cloudformation:CreateStack`

To [assign permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_change-permissions.html) to the user goto https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/home -> users -> select user -> add permission

Try to add this policy with user dimitries.

**Example A sample policy that grants create and view stack actions**

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[{
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":[
            "cloudformation:CreateStack",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
            "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
            "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"  
        ],
        "Resource":"*"
    }]
}
```

You can check this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html) to customize or restick policy to specific resources.

Either you can create custom policy or you can attach the below-existing one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where should i put the above Example A sample ?

Comment: i have selected my user but there is no the option to choose permissions

Comment: let me post screen shot

Comment: that would be more helpful