# lambda deploy Error: Failed to create managed resources: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I get below error when deploying aws lambda function.

```
sam build
sam deploy --guided
```

```
Error: Failed to create managed resources: An error occurred (AccessDenied)
when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/test.person 
is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateChangeSet on
resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-south-1:xxxxx:stack/aws-sam-cli-managed-default/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx
with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy
```

Below is my **IAM permissions** for my account

- AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator
- AWSCloudFormationFullAccess
- Force_MFA
- AWSLambda_FullAccess

Comment: You are `test.person` user?

Comment: @Marcin I have changed the name

Comment: `...explicit deny in an identity-based policy`, something is blocking your user from performing this action. go ask whoever made your account to fix it.

Comment: also asked here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935589/an-error-occurred-accessdenied-when-calling-the-createstack-operation

Comment: without mfa it works @petey

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to deploy your code using Codebuild, You need to attach below policy to your codeBuild Role

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cloudformation:CreateStack",
        "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
        "cloudformation:ListStacks",
        "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
        "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
        "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
},
```